# connection string update in Wix

Tags: wix

I am facing one problem during the installer package creation using Wix for a WCF service. My application is having one wcf form and service. I have added that service as a service reference to that form appication. Application is installing fine. But connection string is not getting updated. Please help me to solve the error. The code is below:

```
 <DirectoryRef Id="Directoryconn">
  <!-- Component handling the web.config -->
  <Component Id="ConnectionSqlAuth" Guid="{7B545D7D-FC59-4CAE-9ADC-DC473690B520}">
    <File Id="fil62C70949D477305C96D703343FBCFD58" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ServiceLibrary_TargetDir)ServiceLibrary.dll.config" />
    <util:XmlFile Id="SetDatabaseConnectionSql" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='DbConnection'[\]]/@connectionString" Value="Data Source=[DB_SERVER];Initial Catalog=[DB_DATABASE];User ID=[DB_USER];Password=[DB_PASSWORD];" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]ServiceLibrary.dll.config" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Sequence="1" />
    <wix:Condition xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">DB_AUTHENTICATION ="SQL Server Authentication"</wix:Condition>
  </Component>

  <!-- Component handling the App.config -->
  <Component Id="ConnectionWindowsAuth" Guid="{5816f7d8-eaa6-4193-a29a-9135e9036007}">
    <File Id="fil62C70949D477305C96D703343FBCFD59" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ServiceLibrary_TargetDir)ServiceLibrary.dll.config" />
    <util:XmlFile Id="SetDatabaseConnectionWindow" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='DbConnection'[\]]/@connectionString" Value="Data Source=[DB_SERVER];Initial Catalog=[DB_DATABASE];Integrated Security=True;" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]ServiceLibrary.dll.config" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Sequence="1" />
    <wix:Condition xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">DB_AUTHENTICATION ="Windows Authentication"</wix:Condition>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```